# Can't insert into database codeigniter but can update

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm having a trouble with CodeIgniter.

I'm following the net tuts tutorial on How to build a CMS with CI. I set the same function save to update and save new item in the database.

```
    public function save($data, $id = NULL){

    // Set timestamps
    if ($this->_timestamps == TRUE) {
        $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $id || $data['created'] = $now;
        $data['modified'] = $now;
    }

    // Insert
    if ($id === NULL) {

        $id = $this->db->insert_id();
        $this->db->set($data);
        $this->db->insert($this->_table_name);
    }
    // Update
    else {
        $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
        $id = $filter($id);
        $this->db->set($data);
        $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
        $this->db->update($this->_table_name);
    }

    return $id;
}
```

The thing is, the update is working correctly, but the Insert is not.

Here is the controller function that he is calling:

```
    public function edit ($id = NULL)
{
    // Fetch a page or set a new one
    if ($id) {
        $this->data['page'] = $this->page_m->get($id);
        count($this->data['page']) || $this->data['errors'][] = 'page could not be found';
    }
    else {
        $this->data['page'] = $this->page_m->get_new();
    }

    // Pages for dropdown
    $this->data['pages_no_parents'] = $this->page_m->get_no_parents();

    // Set up the form
    $rules = $this->page_m->rules;
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

    // Process the form
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
        $data = $this->page_m->array_from_post(array('title','slug','body','parent_id'));
        $this->page_m->save($data, $id);
        redirect('admin/page');
    }

    // Load the view
    $this->data['subview'] = 'pages/admin/page/edit';
    $this->load->view('pages/admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
}
```

I think I gave you enough context

Comment: i watched that tutorial and there is some interesting information. but i would strongly urge you to consider having update and insert as separate methods. its so much easier. saving a few lines of code is not worth it if it makes the application harder to build. always go for readability first. AND you set up a condition where if for some reason the id is not passed - its not going to give you an error - it will keep inserting duplicate records. (sad face)

Comment: yeah, I'm still new to the CI so I did it this way, but in the future I'm going to do in separate methods

Comment: These are still the best codeigniter tutorials: http://net.tutsplus.com/sessions/codeigniter-from-scratch/ There are slight changes from CI 1.7 to CI 2.0 but otherwise they are still very solid.

Answer (score 3):

Hope it works for you:

```
if (!$id) {
    //$this->db->set($data);
    $this->db->insert($this->_table_name, $data);
    $id = $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

### EDIT:

```
else {
    $this->data['page'] = $this->page_m->get_new();
    $id = NULL;
}
```

Comment: It's happening the same thing, it doesn't insert anything on my database and worst of all CI doesn't give me a good error log message to figure out why it doesn't store on the database.